# Why does the "top X%" in my profile change frequently between week/month/all time?

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page, user-rank

The "top X%" counter based on reputation displayed in my user profile seems to be changing between "this month", "this week", and "all time". Why is that? Is there any way that I can toggle between those?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The metric reported on your profile under the big score is your best overall percentage ranking in the leagues over the most recent time periods that are collected and reported.

To see how you fare in the other categories just check the:

- week
- month
- quarter
- year
- all-time

links for the appropriate Stack Exchange site here: [Stack Exchange Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues)

Don't be surprised to see yourself apparently ranked **#1**!  Since you are logged in, the page simply shows your results first and then Jon Skeet's and then everyone else in order.  :-)

There are also easy "Previous Week" and "Next Week" links, e.g., when you get into the league page.

Comment: Interestingly enough, Jon Skeet hasn't been the top weekly, monthly, or quarterly user for quite some time. Darin Dimitrov has been passing him up pretty consistently, and the top user of the week is anyone's prize to grab.

Comment: @Cody: Don't get me wrong, I'm **awfully** impressed with Darin.  Another kind of awesome we have Alex Aza who earned 3k of rep in his first 23 days.  The leagues reveal all that glory.  :-)