# How does 'Top n% this week' work with Reputation league?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation-leagues

On my [Android.SE profile](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/3303/sachin-shekhar), `top 2% this week` is displayed in Reputation box:
[image: Reputation on Android.SE]

But, when I click it, I found that my [week rank](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/54/week/android/2012-03-18/3303#3303) is 1:
[image: Reputation League of Android.SE]

So, how does this `n%` work?

Comment: Looks like its broken for [Chance](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/3415/chance) and [Richard Borcsik](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/13391/richard-borcsik) as well if the accepted answer to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92328/why-does-the-top-x-in-my-profile-change-frequently-between-week-month-all-time) is to be believed

Comment: @ConradFrix Means, I can add `bug` tag..

Comment: Its not broken. See my answer. I have removed bug tag..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now, I get it. At this time situation is:
[image: Reputation League at Android.SE]

Calculating it is easy with this formula: (Rank/No. of Users with Rep Change)*100%
Rank=1; Users with Rep Change in week=104
So, (1/104)*100% = [0.96%](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%281/104%29*100) (after round off)

At the time I asked question, users with rep change were 91. After applying this formula & rounding off after considering percentile rank, it was 2%. I am attaching @balpha's comment here (which explains more):

> The top 2%, by definition, are the users whose rep change is above the
>   98th percentile. The top 1% are those above the 99th percentile. At
>   98.9, your rep change is below the 99th percentile, but above the 98th. Thus, you're in the top 2%, but not in the top 1%.

Comment: Not a bug.  At the time you posted this, you were 1/91 = 1.09%.  100-1.09 gives you 98.9, so you were still just within the top 2%.  It only gets more specific than whole numbers once you get below 1%.

Comment: Nearest rounded no. is 1, not 2.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - We're talking percentiles here, rounding *down* is incorrect...so we round up very intentionally (there's literally a line of code that does this).  If on your SAT you rounded a 99.9% to 100% it would not be correct, you score better than 99% of people, yes, but you did *not* score better than 100%.

Comment: @NickCraver Looks reasonable if its percentile. But, why is `%` symbol used?

Comment: The top 2%, by definition, are the users whose rep change is above the 98th percentile. The top 1% are those above the 99th percentile. At 98.9, your rep change is *below* the 99th percentile, but *above* the 98th. Thus, you're in the top 2%, but not in the top 1%.

Comment: @balpha Thanks.. I have added you comment in answer.

Answer (score 5):

[There were only 104 users with rep changes *this week*](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/54/week/android/2012-03-18?sort=reputationchange&page=3&pageSize=50), so that works out (with rounding) to the top user being the top 2%, the text is correct.

Comment: It was really broken. Now, it has been corrected with `top 0.96% this week`.

Comment: From [answer of this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126648/178465), (1/104)*100 returns 0.96% after round off. Here, 1 is rank & 104 is no. of users having rep change..

Comment: So, remove `status-bydesign` moderator tag from question, please.

Comment: FYI, when this question was first posted, the rep leagues showed 91 people with rep gain.  I think top 2% was correct with regard to *that* number (it would put you right on the edge between top 2% and top 1% if I'm thinking about this correctly).  I meant to post an answer at that time, but I forgot =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 still, its bug because exact value is 1.098% which rounds off to 1%, not 2%.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - that's not a bug, it rounds up **intentionally**, doing otherwise would be incorrect.

Comment: @NickCraver Now, I get it (see my answer). But, you've confused me after calculating it with 104 users (with 104 users, it would be 0.96%)!