# What's the exact mathematical formula of calculating "top n% of this X"?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

After getting the answer of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126550/how-does-top-n-this-week-work-with-reputation-league), I am confused. It says: `n%` is percentage of users having reputation change this X.

Its alright, but how does this no. get smaller for top rankers? If it has to do with user base below it too.. `n%` should be higher with simple maths.

I want to know **exact formula** system uses to calculate it. My concern is `top n%`, not `this X`. I know, `this X` is chosen based on best performance among all X.

Comment: "Its alright, but how does this no. get smaller for top rankers? If it has to do with user base below it too.. n% should be higher with simple maths." Can you explain that a bit? I don't understand this paragraph at all.

Comment: It's a percent, which means by definition *yes*, it depends on how many other users are involved.  The only way the percentage gets smaller is if more items are involved, nothing crazy is happening here it's just a very standard percentile rank.  Can you be more specific about which part isn't clear?

Comment: @sepp2k suppose all users are 100 & users with reputation change are 51. For 50th one, 1 user is below him. For 1st one, 50 users are below him. Percentage of 50 (out of 100) is greater or Percentage of 1? This is what I was saying. But, looks like Juhana has addressed this issue in answer.

Comment: @NickCraver I think, its percentage, not percentile no. And, check my previous comment for what I want to say in question.

Comment: @NickCraver From the answer, it looks like its really percentile no. But, `%` symbol is confusing me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The percentage tells how many users have gained more reputation than you during the time period. For example if it says "top 10% this week" and you have gained 150 reputation this week, it means that 10% of users have gained at least 150 rep during that period (and 90% have gained less than 150).

If you get more reputation, the percentage gets smaller because there are less people who have more rep than that. Similarly if you publish an album it might get to the top 500 list. If the album sells more you get to the "smaller number" ranking lists as the ranking gets higher, top 100, top 50, top 10...

Comment: Your answer seems reasonable, but I want exact formula with which I could calculate that no. for any user..

Comment: Put all users in a list, ordered by reputation. The formula is `x / n` where `x` is the position in the list and `n` is the total amount of users (with reputation gain, I assume).