# Option to choose between %this year %all time %this month etc

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

I understand *why* the "top X%" reputation counter in the user profile changes - it displays *what is currently* one's [best overall percentage over the most recently collected time periods](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92328/why-does-the-top-x-in-my-profile-change-frequently-between-week-month-all-tim).

However, in my case, the percentage that is currently displayed (top this year) is not what I wish to see - I am only interested in tracking `top this week`, or sometimes `top this year`.

Is it possible to over-ride the auto-selection process and choose, say, "% all-time" as the only % stat to display?

If not, is anyone looking for a feature request?

Comment: I believe the choice is made based on what gives you the highest "rank", for what it's worth. E.g. if you are top 1% this quarter, top 5% this year, and top 0.1% all time, then it would show the all time ranking.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but thank you for clarifying/confirming. My request, though, is to make this choice for myself. There are times I wish to see the week/month/year percentage and, as far as I can tell, there is no place to see this *(without manually doing the calcs myself)*. Adding this as an option to one's Profile Settings would be a handy-dandy addition to Preferences, is all I'm saying...